# Raspberry Pi GPIO ValueError: "The channel sent is invalid on a Raspberry Pi"

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm currently coding 2 button switches and have stumbled across a problem. I'm getting invalid channel errors when running my code. I'm guessing my RPi.GPIO lib needs to be updated; as it seems i'm only able to use 26 pins. 
Here is an example:

`import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.OUT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The channel sent is invalid on a Raspberry Pi`

Anyone have any suggestions? 
Thank you

Comment: Latest board old library or old library newest board or  root  permission ? Ex: `i have pi XX model, my library is X.XXX`

Comment: It's a B+, I'm not sure how to find the library version

Comment: you haven't No:40 pin ! Because you used `GPIO` module. Pin and module number can't be equal.[check](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Raspberry-Pi-GPIO-Layout-Model-B-Plus-rotated-2700x900-1024x341.png)

Comment: Thank you for your help sir.